# Materializecss tooltip not showing up

Tags: tooltip, materialize

I am trying to use materialize tool tip for the first time using the example shown on its website. However, the tool tip is not showing up. What am I missing? Here is the link to the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/L013uvms/5/

```
 <textarea id="causative_micro_organisms" class="materialize-textarea tooltipped" data-position="top" data-tooltip="I am a tooltip" required="" aria-required="true"></textarea>
<label for="causative_micro_organisms">What are the LIKELY causative Micro-organisms?</label>
```

I have also initialized the tool-tip

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').formSelect();
  $('.tooltipped').tooltip();
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

It may works but it's invisible. Check if `.material-tooltip` background color in `_tooltip.scss` is transparent. If yes, set it to desired color. In my case I set it to black:

```css
.material-tooltip {
 ...
 background-color: black;
 ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

as docs of materialize website add these before document ready

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
 var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.tooltipped');
 var instances = M.Tooltip.init(elems, options);
});
```

related link https://materializecss.com/tooltips.html

Comment: Thanks, this does help. However, the documentation says use either the above code or initialize with jquery which I had already done. Any clue why jquery initialization method was not sufficient?